# python code to extract highlighted text in PDF and create a new PDF which contains this highlighted text

Tags: python, pdf

I have been trying to extract highlighted text from a PDF and create a new PDF which contains only this highlighted text.

I was trying with poppler library in python but it's not getting installed using pip.

I was getting version problem.

Comment: please paste the error message you are getting into the question

Comment: I lost the error. But please tell how to install PyQt4 and popplerqt4 . In this link code is there which uses above two packages , https://gist.github.com/Samathy/8e4447e455966cb80f5d484042c8be79 .